# How do you implement a multi-purpose socket protocol?

Tags: java, io

I am building a client/server media application for personal use. The application works, but I have two sockets per connection: one for server/client commands and communication (just sending JSON strings back and forth; and the other for sending the serialized media.

How can I merge the two sockets in a fashion that I know what data is what, or is it better to just leave them as they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define a structure to your messages to use a single socket for both.  For example:

```
Message format:
  Command,DataLen,Data

Example messages:
  JSON,20,{ "text": "Hello!" }

  CMD1:9:Some Data
```

That is "text-based" format using comma to separate the command from the data-length, from the data.  You could use a binary format (which is probably easier to parse and more robust), for example:

```
CommandLen(4-bytes):Command:DataLen(4-bytes):Data
```

Comment: @EvanTeran, brettw How does this support raw binary streaming? As far as I know, there is no way to put raw binary into a JSON string. Obviously I can send a JSON message saying 'hey, client expect xxx binary data', but this doesn't address message / binary data synchronisation.

Comment: If I were to send binary data over encoded in JSON, I would probably just use base64 encoding. it's simple and has relatively small inflation of the data size.

Comment: @EvanTeran Thanks for the advice. I did a simple Arrays.toString(byte[]) and back again benchmark and compared it to Base64. You win. Thanks again, I didn't know about the epicness of Bas64.

Comment: The numbers (for any who care)<br> 2ms avg to decode is base64.<br> 57ms avg to decode with brute force.